# Issue with RHEL8/CentOS8 remote virt-viewer and firewalld

Tags: kvm-virtualization, rhel8

In our lab we have a RHEL8 server with developer subscription.
On the machine we have a few VMs and some of them are on a private libvirt network, thus we can only access them via `virt-viewer`.

- We use various Fedora 32/33 to connect to the lab server.
- We can ssh to the server and personally I can even ssh as root (`ssh root@server.example.com` works)

The command I use is:

```sh
virt-viewer -c qemu+ssh://root@server.example.com/system privatevm
```

My problem:

- When I have `firewalld` up and running on the server, `virt-viewer` cannot open the display. We only see the `Connected to graphic server` message on the `virt-viewer` and the rest is just gray. USB redirection is enabled, but not the "Screenshot", or the "Preferences". But no graphical output.
- When I stop `firewalld` virt-viewer displays the remote machine/desktop just fine.

I enabled logging on the firewalld. I don't see any dropped packages to/from the client. I am out of ideas, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the firewalld configuration?

Comment: I would say sufficient. I mean, I have all the necessary services enabled. For example: 
ssh, libvirt, libvirt-tls. 

Please note that virsh -c qemu+ssh:// and virsh -c qemu+tls work just fine from any client. 

Also, please note that the issue is not only via virt-viewer. virt-manager has the same problem when I open the console.

Answer (score 0):

To help troubleshooting.

Ensure that the *libvirt-daemon-config-network* package is installed:

```
# yum info libvirt-daemon-config-network
Installed Packages
Name         : libvirt-daemon-config-network
[...]
```

Verify that the *libvirt* default network is active and configured to start automatically:

```
# virsh net-list --all
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
```

If it is not, activate the default network and set it to auto-start:

```
# virsh net-autostart default
Network default marked as autostarted

# virsh net-start default
Network default started
```

If activating the default network fails with the following error, the libvirt-daemon-config-network package has not been installed correctly.

```
error: failed to get network 'default'
error: Network not found: no network with matching name 'default'
```

To fix this, re-install *libvirt-daemon-config-network*.

```
# yum reinstall libvirt-daemon-config-network
```

Comment: Default network is up, and of course it's enabled to start automatically. Please note though that the default network is bridge and not NAT. 
I cannot confirm the packages now, I will return in a couple of days when I will have access to the server. 

However, I have to point out that the default network obviously is not an issue, since I can ssh to the VM, which gets an IP from the DHCP server of the lab.